# Want an exception upon BIRT JavaScript errors

Tags: javascript, birt

I have a report in BIRT that has non-trivial JavaScript (scripted data source). The JavaScript is all a bit wobbly, and suspect to regress. For that reason and others I have written a JUnit test that populates the data, runs the report (`createRunAndRenderTask` and run that task) and do some validation on the resulting report.

Obviously this test will fail when the BIRT engine throws any exceptions. However, upon JavaScript errors in the report, no exceptions are thrown. And that does not feel good. Can I change this somehow to have the BIRT engine throw exceptions upon JavaScript errors?

I tried this by having a host of JavaScript errors during development of the report. Think of typos in the scripted data source. They are spit out in the console, but no exceptions.

E.g.:

```
<method name="open"><![CDATA[count = 0;
this should break]]></method>
```

This shows in the console:

```
... Fail to execute script in function __bm_OPEN(). Source:
------
" + count = 0;

this should break + "
-----
A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
ReferenceError: "this should break" is not defined. (/report/data-sets/script-data-set[@id="9"]/method[@name="open"]#3)
```

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing this and pretty okay with it:

```
IRunAndRenderTask task = ...
...

task.setErrorHandlingOption(IEngineTask.CANCEL_ON_ERROR);
...

task.run();
evaluateStatus(task, reportName);
task.close();
```

And:

```
private void evaluateStatus(IRunAndRenderTask task, String reportName) {
    if (task.getStatus() == IEngineTask.STATUS_CANCELLED) {
        String message = "report failed: " + reportName;
        List<Throwable> errors = task.getErrors();
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException(message, errors.get(errors.size() - 1));
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on javascript errors, the BIRT engine will catch them and still try to display the report.

I think you could override this by wrapping your javascript code  (Rhino script) in a try...catch expression, and explicitely throw a BirtException if something wrong happens:

```
try{
   //your javascript stuff
   var test=null;
   test.toString();
}catch(e){
   var exception=new org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.BirtException("Custom exception:"+e);
   throw exception;
}
```

Comment: This does not work per se. But it made me thinking, used the exception to get the stack trace, to understand where to go look, so definitely useful. I'll post my own answer :)